# JNA: invalid memory access with callback function parameter (struct)

Tags: jna

To lone travelers stumbling upon this: see comments for the answer.

...

Writing a Java wrapper for a native library. A device generates data samples and stores them as structs. Two native ways of accessing them: either you request one with a `getSample(&sampleStruct)` or you set a callback function. Now, here is what does work:

- The polling method does fill the JNA Structure
- The callback function is called after being set
- In fact, I am currently getting the sample right from the callback function

The problem: trying to do anything with the callback argument, which should be a struct, causes an "invalid memory access". Declaring the argument as the Structure does this, so I declared it as a Pointer. Trying a `Pointer.getInt(0)` causes invalid memory access. So then I declared the argument as an int, and an int is delivered; in fact, it looks very much like the first field of the struct I am trying to get! So does it mean that the struct *was* at that address but disappeared before Java had time to access it?

This is what I am doing now:

```
public class SampleCallback implements Callback{
    SampleStruct sample;

    public int callback(Pointer refToSample) throws IOException{
        lib.INSTANCE.GetSample(sample); // works no problem
        adapter.handleSample(sample);
        return 1;
    } ...
```

But neither of these does:

```
public int callback(SampleStruct sample) throws IOException{
        adapter.handleSample(sample);
        return 1;
    }
```

...

```
public int callback(Pointer refToSample) throws IOException{
    SampleStruct sample = new SampleStruct();
    sample.timestamp = refToSample.getInt(0);
    ...
    adapter.handleSample(sample);
    return 1;
}
```

Also, this does in fact deliver the timestamp,

```
 public int callback(int timestamp) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("It is " + timestamp + "o'clock");
        return 1;
 }
```

but I would really prefer the whole struct.

This is clearly not going to be a popular topic and I do have a working solution, so the description is not exactly full. Will copy anything else that might be helpful if requested. Gratitude prematurely extended.

Comment: What do the native (C) signatures look like?

Comment: If your callback is `invoke(struct)` rather than `invoke(struct*)`, then you'll need make the Java signature refect that with the `Structure.ByValue` tagging interface, e.g. `invoke(<T extends Structure.ByValue>)`.

Comment: Thank you! Your conclusion was right, that's exactly what the problem was. Had to change `public class SampleStructure extends Structure` to `public class SampleStructure extends Structure implements Structure.ByValue`. Tried using a `public class SampleStructure implements Structure.ByValue` before (sure is stupid in hindsight), but the error being the same as in many other cases threw me off. Thanks for pointing out the right direction!